# Undefined variable: idletime

Tags: php

here is my code....

```
class line{
    function db($host, $user, $pass, $db){
        mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could Not Connect to Database or Database Does not Exists....");
        mysql_select_db($db) or die("Database Does not Exists....");
    }

    $idletime = 300;
    $deltime = 600;

     function test(){
    echo $idletime;
    echo idletime;
}

}
```

and calling this class as

```
$w = new line();
$w->test();
```

but it says

Undefined variable: idletime in *****

please let me know what acutally the problem is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable is a [class property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) *-- or, at least, I'm guessing that's what you want it to be...*

This line inside your `test` method :

```
echo $idletime;
```

Is trying to access a variable defined inside that method *-- not a class property*.

And there is no such local variable -- hence the notice.

To access a class property, you need to use `$this`, this way :

```
echo $this->idletime;
```

Also, your code is not valid : you have to declare that your "variables" are indeed class properties -- i.e., you need to use some of the [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) keywords in front of them.

Here's you class, once re-written :

```
class line {
    function db($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could Not Connect to Database or Database Does not Exists....");
        mysql_select_db($db) or die("Database Does not Exists....");
    }

    protected $idletime = 300;
    protected $deltime = 600;

    public function test(){
        echo $this->idletime;
    }
}
```

I have :

- Set your properties as `protected`
- And I'm using `$this` to access them from inside the `test` method
- I have also indicated the `test` method is `public` -- it's the default, but I like being explicit about it.

Don't hesitate to spend some time reading the [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) section of the manual : you'll learn lots of useful stuff ;-)

Comment: +1 I overlooked that $idletime is within the class. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variables into your function call,

```
function test($idletime){
    echo $idletime;
    echo idletime;
}
```

Or it could be that the variable is out scope define them as global first

Comment: What about that line that says: echo idletime?